# Web browser awesomium and geckofx scrolling error

Tags: vb.net, awesomium, geckofx

I'm creating a two version of web browser made with awesomium and geckofx but I noticed something when the page is too long it I can't scroll down.
How to fix this?

Thank you

Here's a picture of it for reference
[image: Scrolling problem]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

It was a poorly coded header that causing this sorry.

I check my header and found out that before the 

there is a javascript

removing it fixed the problem.